# elasticsearch find posts by comments

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to write a query that finds articles based on their comments.

So if a user is trying to find "chocolates"

```
{
  type: "article",
  id: "myArticle1",
  title: "something about brown food"
}

{
  body: "I love chocolates!",
  type:"comment",
  commentOf: "myArticle1"
}
```

In this example I have both documents in the same index and I'm trying to get the "myArticle1" document via the comment matching chocolates in body. How do I do this? Is it with the top_children query?

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done in one query. Getting all IDs (contents of `commentOf` field) based on keywords present in the `body` and then using these IDs to retrieve the articles would do it, but with 2 calls instead of one. If the 2nd document is registered as the child of the first one, though, it's indeed possible to query parent documents based on the contents of children (`has_child` with a query for the necessary properties of the child).

Comment: @Ashalynd what are the requirements of registering a child? Do you think I should denormalize or just go with 2 queries? Either one is fine with me I just didn't want to miss out on some trick of doing it with one normal query.

Comment: Have a look at this article to get a better idea regarding document relations in ES: http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/ Which way you should choose is up to you. To me, comments look like natural children of the article, so it might make sense to index them as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the parent-child in ES to achieve this:

1. Define the parent (article) and child (comment)
2. Index data. You should know how to index child data as it will difference from normal (need to specify parent in the index request)
3. Use `has_child` query to query for `article` that matched some
   fields in `comment`

I wrote a full working sample script for it: https://gist.github.com/dqduc/efa66047358dac66461b

You can run it to test and send me your feedback. I guess you're new to ES and parent-child relationship in ES.

Comment: Glad that it help. If it solved your problem, you can mark it as correct answer, to help others that face same issues

Comment: Is it possible for the parent to be of the same type?

Comment: Yes you can use `nested document` in ES to define `comments` as property of `article` document. The drawback is indexing performance if `comments` is updated frequency. You can refer http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/, or http://obtao.com/blog/2014/04/elasticsearch-advanced-search-and-nested-objects/, and decide which is good for your situation

Comment: @Duc.Duong - The link in the answer is not working ( https://gist.github.com/tintin04/efa66047358dac66461b ) , could you please check it?  Thank You.

Comment: @Bujji I updated the link. BTW parent/child types is dropped since ES 6.x+, you will need to port to other ways, eg JOIN: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html

Comment: @Duc.Duong - Thanks for updating the link and also for the JOIN link.